# Webpack and fonts: module parse failed

Tags: css, webpack, webfonts

I'm trying to use FontAwesome in my app. I'm using webpack to do it's magic. My config is:

```
  resolve: {
    // you can now require('myfile') instead of require('myfile.cjsx')
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.cjsx', '.coffee']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: commonLoaders.concat([
      { test: /\.css$/, loader : 'style-loader!css-loader' },
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2))(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/, loader : 'file-loader' },
      { test: /\.cjsx$/, loaders: ['react-hot', 'coffee', 'cjsx']},
      { test: /\.coffee$/, loader: 'coffee' },
      { test: /\.jsx$|\.js$/, loader: 'jsx-loader?harmony' },
    ])
  }
```

I'm requesting FontAwesome CSS like that:

```
require "../../styles/font-awesome.min.css";
```

font-awesome.min.css contains this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

And for some reason, WebPack tries to parse .woff file with style-loader and gives me error:

```
ERROR in ./src/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff
Module parse failed: /var/www/app/src/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff Line 1: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./~/css-loader!./src/styles/font-awesome.min.css 2:73-117
```

I'm really lost right now. Any ideas?

**Update:**
I'm completely lost right now. I've decided to fool around with my config and put this line in loaders:

```
{ test: /\.eot$/, loader : 'file' },
```

And required this file:

```
require "../../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot";
```

Got error:

```
ERROR in ./src/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot
Module parse failed: /var/www/app/src/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot Line 2: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

However, when I tried to require my file like this:

```
require "file!../../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot";
```

Everything went smooth. Looks like webpack ignores my loaders?

Comment: you can look at https://github.com/guillaumevincent/webpack-bootstrap-fontawesome

Answer (score 8):

1. it depends on the url used in css.
2. this error is releated to regex, try to change `(\?[a-z0-9]+)` to `(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])` or `(\?[\s\S]+)`.

**Example:**

https://github.com/gowravshekar/font-awesome-webpack

```
module.exports = {
       module: {
         loaders: [
         // the url-loader uses DataUrls.
         // the file-loader emits files.
           { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
           { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
        ]
      }
    };
```

https://github.com/shakacode/font-awesome-loader

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // the url-loader uses DataUrls.
      // the file-loader emits files.
      {
        test: /\.woff2?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        // Limiting the size of the woff fonts breaks font-awesome ONLY for the extract text plugin
        // loader: "url?limit=10000"
        loader: "url"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
        loader: 'file'
      },
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The other day I add the `font-awesome` through the LESS source so basically

```
npm install --save less-loader
bower install --save components-font-awesome
```

Then I require font awesome like this

```
require('bower_components/components-font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less')
```

And finally in the `webpack.config.js` I add the loader modules

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {

    ...

    , module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.less$/, loader: "style!css!less"},
            {test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'},
            {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
            {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
            {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
        ]
    } 
};
```

I know that it not the same with `.css` but I believe that its easy this way. Hope it helps.